# Special Characters and Spaces are not transferred correctly via AJAX call.

Tags: jquery, urls

I am using a custom ajax call for a Glossary Like Page getting data from a custom table in Wordpress. I can search for words and terms and I am correctly getting all contents.

I have several words which are linked to different contents inside the text. When I click for instance a linked word like "Training" I am correctly linked to the words content. When I click a term containing more than one word I am getting an error that the object can't be found. For instance `Tuesday Training` - I am getting `tuesday%20training` and the datasearch does not work. Same for special characters like ó, ä, ü, etc.

I am using this call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                        url: my_ajax.ajaxurl,
                        type:'GET',
                        dataType:"html",
                        data: {
                            action: 'myajax_search',
                            search_data:mysearch
                        }
```

Any idea to get Ajax correctly get spaces and special characters encoded? The page is in UTF8 without BOM.

When I use the normal search I am getting special charcters,

Thank you!

Comment: You need to [`urldecode()`](https://secure.php.net/urldecode) in your PHP function

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - do you mean inside the functions.php function? I am not sure where to change it. I tried out replace in the js code which helps with more than one word, but it doesn't help with the wrong encoding. So help would still be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in your PHP code where you are reading the `search_data` variable